# How can I find a saved Wi-Fi password?

Tags: wifi-password

I have an Android phone which is connected to a secured Wi-Fi hotspot.  How can I find out the password of the hotspot from the phone?

Comment: Those looking for a non-root solution, see [Retrieve WiFi password](//android.stackexchange.com/a/199804)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On my phone, the credentials are stored in `/data/wifi/bcm_supp.conf`.  You'll probably need root to see it directly on your phone but you may be able to use `adb pull` (requires the Android SDK) from your PC to get the file.

As noted in the comments, the location may vary based on your ROM or device (specifically the Wi-Fi chip; mine's a Broadcom).  Check `/data/wifi/`, `/data/etc/wifi/` and `/data/misc/wifi/` for relevant config files if you don't find the ones suggested by eldarerathis or me.

Comment: Hm, interesting. What type of phone are you using ATM? I don't have that file, but I was just about to post an answer saying to look for `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`. Maybe WPA Supplicant is just a CyanogenMod thing...

Comment: The name and location of the file vary per device, but it should be either one or the other.

Answer (score 10):

On CyanogenMod devices, and possibly other AOSP ROMs, you should be able to grab it from the `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` file. On a non-rooted device I don't think this is possible since you won't have permission to read the `/data` directories where the settings are stored and the Settings menu simply displays `(Unchanged)` if you go into the network configuration.

This is what I see on my CM7 EVO (network name and password redacted):

```
# cd /data/misc/wifi/
# ls
sockets              wpa_supplicant.conf
# more wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=eth0
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="SomeWifiNetwork"
        psk="MyPlaintextPassword"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        priority=1
}
#
```

Comment: My phone is rooted. I have 'superuser' app installed. But how can I get 'adb shell' with root accessed.  I tried '$ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ su
Permission denied
1|shell@android:/ $ cd /data
shell@android:/data $ ls
opendir failed, Permission denied
255|shell@android:/data $ su
Permission denied
1|shell@android:/data $

Comment: Ah, this is actually a new setting in CyanogenMod. You'll need to use `su` to get a root shell, but first check in `Settings->Developer Options` (your phone's main settings) to see what the "Root Access" setting is. By default it is "Apps only". You'll need to switch it to "Apps and ADB" in order for `su` to work from the shell.

Comment: @michael I always do `adb root` followed by `adb shell`.

Answer (score 5):

In Android Oreo and Pie (tested on OnePlus 6), the file seems to be `/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml` which stores your Wi-Fi credentials. I do not know of a good XML parser, but the file can be opened in a text editor (**requires root access**). Search with the name of your Wifi (SSID) and locate the line containing:

```
<string name="SSID">&quot;YOUR_SAVED_SSID;</string>
```

One of the following lines would show the password. It would be mentioned as "PreSharedKey". Example:

```
<string name="PreSharedKey">&quot;SAVED_PASSWORD;</string>
```

Comment: This `PreSharedKey` doesn't seem to contain plain-text version of the password on Android 8

Comment: @Ruslan your OEM might have kept it encrypted. Samsung especially is known to do it. Mine is not encrypted.

Comment: For me it worked. Thanks.