# How to find saved wifi password?

Tags: wifi-password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out the wifi password from android setting](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21296/how-can-i-find-out-the-wifi-password-from-android-setting)

A friend entered his wifi password into my android phone so that I could connect to his network.

I don't want to ask him again for the password and I want to use it on my laptop.

how can I find the password that he entered?

thanks.

Comment: If it really is your friend, just ask for the password.

Answer (score -2):

There is an option in the setting to display "show passwords" on all. So basically when you click on the WiFi name in "Wireless and Networks" you will find the password.

Comment: This only works when you're in the act of entering the password. Once it's entered re-opening the settings will not show it to you.