# Is there a way to tell my phone to prefer some SSIDs above others?

Tags: wi-fi

Use case: my internet provider offers wi-fi hotspots all over the country; I like to connect to them, but not when I'm home or at work. My phone seems to use one of the available wi-fi connections randomly; I end up 'forgetting' the provider's hotspot to assure connection to the wi-fi at home or at the office.

Windows 7 allows me to change the order of preference of wi-fi connections; that way I can tell my laptop to connect to my provider's hotspot only when no 'better' wi-fi is available.

Does Android have something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything built-in for this, although some manufacturers may have added such a feature.  [There appear to be several apps that will do this.](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=wi-fi%20priority)

I've always just manually edited `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` myself (root required).  (Note that [there are different files/locations](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/21297/1465) for different devices.)

Comment: Yupp, beat me to it – I've had the same thought (so +1 is a must ;) For a "better listing", [see here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_automation#group_999) – not as complete, maybe, but hand-picked :)

Comment: How can I edit that file? Doesn't that require a rooted phone? Or can I do that via adb?

Comment: To edit that file you need to root your device. But most of the tools in the place I've linked in my previous comment (just added a few more there) can change the priority without root.

Comment: An app just needs [WRITE_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS) to do this, I believe.  I am not sure if `adb` has that permission, but it cannot access the file directly without root.